# Android: Callback to fragment from DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I know to pass back something from a fragment to its calling activity you can use onAttach which has the "activity" parameter. You can set the activity to variable and call an interface on it later. So passing data from the fragment back to the activity. All great.

I would like to do the same thing  but this time i have a standard fragment and I want to call a `DialogFragment` and then have the `DialogFragment` call back to the original fragment but I can't use `onAttach` is wants a `Activity`.

Anyone know the best way of doing this ?

Thanks

Comment: try looking at: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: FragmentManager , id or tags, backstackentry are the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you could just make things public in your activity and set them from your fragment. But then you have to keep references to your activity, and possibly have unwanted public variables and/or setters.

You could use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and you would not need any of that.

In your activity you need to register an event

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}

// This method will be called when a MessageEvent is posted
public void onEvent(MessageEvent event){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Then you can simply call your event from your fragment or anywhere you like,

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("Hello everyone!"));
```

Some more information on EventBus can be found [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md)
And [another possibly useful tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-the-eventbus-library--cms-22694).

Comment: Nice!, I like that. Just out of interest i found Otto which is supposed to be similar. Do you have experience? I was wondering which is recommended. But I do really like it.  Better than creating interfaces and passing them around or having public methods!

Comment: I have looked at `Otto` and yeah they are similar. but I have not used it, `EventBus` seems to be able to do everything I need. I have also seen this comparison page: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/COMPARISON.md

Answer (score 1):

One way to contact another fragment from there is to access it in the implemented method in your `Activity`:

```
//In your Activity...

@Override
public void callbackFromFragmentA(){
    FragmentB fragment = (FragmentB) getFragmentManager.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.callFragmentMethod();
    }
}
```